# Finding the length of each sentence in a text

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm new to python (and coding in general), and I ran into an issue while doing my first assignment for school. We need to implement several simple text analysis techniques, and after hours of hitting my head on my keyboard, I figured I better ask for some pointers here.
The problem lies within one of the tasks. I'm supposed to find the number of words per sentence in a given text, and then print out the number of words per sentence from the longest to the shortest. Thus far, I have been able to figure out how to find the longest and shortest sentence, (and even the second longest sentence). However, I'm stuck as to how to find out the second shortest sentence or third longest, etc.
My code looks like this:

```
length = sentences.split(". ")
tokenized_sentences = [sentence.split(" ") for sentence in length]
longest_sen = max(tokenized_sentences, key=len)
longest_sen_length = len(longest_sen)
shortest_sen = min(tokenized_sentences, key=len)
shortest_sen_length = len(shortest_sen)    
print("The longest sentence is", (longest_sen_length), "words.")
print("The shortest sentence is", (shortest_sen_length), "words.")
```

I'm aware that the code is not robust, and I could save a lot of time using nltk or re. However, the paragraph isn't very long or complex, and I'm not certain my professor would be a-ok with me using an additional platform at this point.
Any pointers would be highly appreciated!

**Edit:** An example of the text: "Once more. Say, you are in the country, in some high land of lakes. Take almost any path you please, and ten to one it carries you down in a dale, and leaves you there by a pool in the stream. There is magic in it. Let the most absentminded of men be plunged in his deepest reveries--stand that man on his legs, set his feet a-going, and he will infallibly lead you to water, if water there be in all that region. Should you ever be athirst in the great American desert, try this experiment, if your caravan happen to be supplied with a metaphysical professor. Yes, as every one knows, meditation and water are wedded for ever."

Comment: Are you familiar with `sorted()`? https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: can you post an example of a sentence ?

Comment: At least for me the names of some of your variables are somehow misleading and make it hard to follow the code. For me `sentences` should be called `text` and the list that you called `length` should be called `sentences`. `length` is a weird name for a list of sentences.

Comment: I am! The problem I'm having with it is that I necessarily need to include something like ‘The longest sentence in this text contains “X” words”. The second longest sentence in this text contains “Z” words. The shortest sentence in this text contains “Y” words., etc." Which at this point I don't know how to combine with sorted(). But I'll look into the link to see if I can get unstuck. Thanks!

Comment: @Matthias thanks you for bringing that up. I will definitely change things around so it's more understandable. As it is right now, I know what each section does, but I should start with the habit of making it more comprehensible from the get-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that your entire test is named sentences, then you can do the following, that sorts the sentences by length (descending).

```
l=sentences.split('. ')
m=[len(i.split()) for i in l]
m.sort(reverse=True)
```

And you will have all sentences lengths and you can play around with what you want to print

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect and it's letting me play around with the text as much as I wand/need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sort() method to sort a list based on the length and you want descending order, so just put reverse = True.

```
tokenized_sentences.sort(key=len,reverse = True)
```